# "Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error" using grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I want to use grunt to run jasmine tests automatically. I have never done that before and I am constantly facing errors I don't understand...
I want to use [`grunt-contrib-jasmine`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine) and [`grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs`](https://github.com/cloudchen/grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs).
I added this to my grunt file:

```
jasmine: {
    jasmine_tests: {
        src: 'public/js/app/**/*.js',
        options: {
            specs: 'spec/*Spec.js',
            helpers: 'spec/*Helper.js',
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
            templateOptions: {
                requireConfig: {
                    baseUrl: '',
                    paths: {
                        "i18n": "../libs/require-i18next/require-i18next/i18next",
                        "i18next-builder": "../libs/require-i18next/require-i18next/i18next-builder",
                        "jquery": "../libs/jquery/dist/jquery",
                        ...
                    },
                    shim: {
                        "jquerymobile": ["jquery"],
                        ....
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

When I run `grunt jasmine` i get hundreds of errors. It seems that not a single file can be loaded.

> > Running "jasmine:jasmine_tests" (jasmine) task
> >
> > Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS
> >
> > Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error: ['jquery'] at
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3_SpecRunner.html:38 
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:12 v
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:30 
> >     Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error: ['underscore'] at
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3_SpecRunner.html:38 
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:12 v
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:30
>
> ...
>
> > Error: timeout: Load timeout for modules: i18n!locales_unnormalized2,datatables,sortDate...
>
> ...
>
> > http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout at
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3_SpecRunner.html:38 
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:12 v
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:14 C
> >     ..........\C:\Users\Garrarufa\Documents\WebstormWorkspace\website3.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:14
> >
> > Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to an unfinished async spec. Use --force to continue.
> >
> > Aborted due to warnings.

My specs are int the folder `.../website3/specs`, my requirejs module definitions that I want to test are in the folder `.../webiste3/public/js/app/**`.
What is going wrong and what do I have to change?
I don't really understand what i have to define in the gruntfile and in requireConfig. Maybe this has to do with it?

My directory structure:

```
- website3
    - .grunt
        + grunt-contrib-jasmine
    + node_modules
    - public
        - js
            - app
                + collections
                - config
                    > config.js
                + ...
                - views
                    + ...
                    > AddVehicleView.js
                    > ...
        + libs
        > index.html
    + server
    - spec
        + helpers
        - support
            > jasmine.json
        > AddVehicleViewSpec.js
    > .bowerrc
    > ...
    > _SpecRunner.html
    > Gruntfile.js
    > package.json
```